# How do I structure the layout of my shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a simple shiny app, and would love to structure my app in a certain way. See screenshot below -

[image]

Some things to highlight -

1. The solid line below the value boxes
2. In 3 sections with the sales map, sales trend plot and bar plot, is it possible to have a title for those sections, along with an info action button which I'll use to provide more info about the chart?

I am able to create the sidebar and value boxes with the code below, however I have trouble understanding how to use columns and/or boxes "below" the value boxes. See code below -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI ----
ui <- navbarPage(
    useShinydashboard(),
    
    title = "My App",
    tabPanel(
        "Tab1", icon = icon("home"),
        fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    width = 2,
                    dateRangeInput(inputId   = "date_range",
                                   label     = h4("Date Range"),
                                   start     = as.Date("2018-01-01"),
                                   end       = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
                                   min       = as.Date("2018-01-01"),
                                   max       = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
                                   startview = "year"
                    )
                ),
                
                mainPanel(
                    # Value Box 1
                    valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_1", width = 3),
                    
                    # Value Box 2
                    valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_2", width = 3),
                    
                    # Value Box 3
                    valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_3", width = 3),
                    
                    # Value Box 4
                    valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_4", width = 3),
                    
                    br(),
                    hr()
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {

    # Box 1
    output$box_1 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
        valueBox(5, "box1", color = "green"
        )
    })
    
    # Box 2
    output$box_2 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(10, "box2", color = "blue"
        )
    })
    
    # Box 3
    output$box_3 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(15, "box1", color = "purple"
        )
    })
    
    # Box 4
    output$box_4 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(20, "box1", color = "orange"
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS) # for popovers

# UI ----
ui <- navbarPage(
  #useShinydashboard(),
  
  title = "My App",
  tabPanel(
    "Tab1", icon = icon("home"),
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          width = 2,
          dateRangeInput(inputId   = "date_range",
                         label     = h4("Date Range"),
                         start     = as.Date("2018-01-01"),
                         end       = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
                         min       = as.Date("2018-01-01"),
                         max       = as.Date("2020-12-31"),
                         startview = "year"
          )
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
          fluidRow(
            # Value Box 1
            valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_1", width = 3),
            # Value Box 2
            valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_2", width = 3),
            # Value Box 3
            valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_3", width = 3),
            # Value Box 4
            valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box_4", width = 3),
          ),
          
          tags$hr(),
          br(),
          
          fluidRow(

            column(
              width = 6,
              tags$fieldset(
                tags$legend("Plot 1", tags$span(id = "info1", icon("info-circle"))),
                plotOutput("plot1", height = "600px")
              )
            ),
            
            bsPopover(
              "info1",
              title = "This is plot 1",
              content = "This plot is nice",
              placement = "left"
            ),

            column(
              width = 6,
              tags$fieldset(
                tags$legend("Plot 2"),
                plotOutput("plot2", height = "300px")
              ),
              tags$fieldset(
                tags$legend("Plot 3", heigh = "300px"),
                plotOutput("plot3")
              )
            ),
            
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Box 1
  output$box_1 <- shinydashboard::renderValueBox({
    valueBox(5, "box1", color = "green")
  })
  
  # Box 2
  output$box_2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(10, "box2", color = "blue")
  })
  
  # Box 3
  output$box_3 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(15, "box1", color = "purple")
  })
  
  # Box 4
  output$box_4 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(20, "box1", color = "orange")
  })
  
  ####
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. One last thing. How do I adjust the value box sizes to fill up the main panel. I set a width of 3 and there is still some space at the end of the 4th box. I adjusted the with to 4 but that makes one box drop to the next line. A width of 3.5 also does not work.